# parse list in python with \t

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

I have a file, each line looks like this:

```
#each line is a list: 
a = ['1\t2\t3\t4\t5']
#type(a) is list
#str(a) shows as below:
["['1\\t2\\t3\\t4\\t5']"]
```

I want an output of only 1 2 3 4 5, how should I accomplish that? Thanks everyone.

Comment: `[i.replace('\t',' ') for i in a]`?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()`?

Comment: I think I solved this one by using list(str(a)[2:-2].split('\\t')) but this seems over complicated the problem.

Comment: I'm still not clear on the actual appearance of the line in the file, or the object or data structure you want to end up with.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm trying to get a list eventually, then count how many 1,2,3,4,5 is there in the whole file.

Comment: "I want a list" doesn't tell us anything about what it should look like, or what the file contents look like, or how they're related.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Hi, I want the output looks like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

Comment: That doesn't tell us what the actual content of the file looks like, or how it's related to that output. If you can provide some concrete information, we will be able to post more useful solutions instead of just making guesses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84849/discussion-between-user3596895-and-tigerhawkt3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading lines from a file, you can use the following approach:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        print line.replace("\t"," "),
```

If the file you are reading from is actually columns of data, then the following approach might be suitable:

```
import csv

with open("file.txt", "r") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter="\t")

    for cols in csv_input:
        print " ".join(cols)
```

`cols` would give you a list of columns for each row in the file, i.e. `cols[0]` would be the first column. You can then easily print them out with spaces as shown.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your reply, you are right about the delimiter, I complicated the whole thing by putting delimiter as ',' thinking that it's a csv file must be comma delimited, but in fact it is '\t' delimited, so now everything solved.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Bhargav Rao. Use a for loop.

```
for i in a:    
    i.replace('\t',' ') 
    print i
```

I believe it will print out the way you want.
Otherwise please specify.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways of doing this.
you can use a `for` loop or you can just `join` the list and replace all the `\t`

```
a = ['1\t2\t3\t4\t5']

a = "".join(a).replace("\t", "")
print(a)
```